# Optmising the SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query which I have written in SQL which is working fine but I need to optimize the query

Here is my query:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE Connection4_Alt @StartLocation VARCHAR(MAX),@EndLocation VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
WITH T1 AS(
select Distinct  t1.Train_No as Train_1,t1.Train_Name as Train_Name1,t2.Train_No as Train_2,t2.Train_Name as Train_Name2,t3.Train_No as Train_3,t3.Train_Name as Train_Name3,t4.Train_No as Train_4,t4.Train_Name as Train_Name4,
((Select Max(t4.Distance) as MaxDistance From Rail t4 where t4.Train_No=t1.Train_No) - t1.Distance) as Distance_1, (Select Max(t4.Distance)  From Rail t4 where t4.Train_No=t2.Train_No) as Distance_2 ,(Select Max(t4.Distance)  From Rail t4 where t4.Train_No=t3.Train_No) as  Distance_3,t4.Distance as Distance_4,
t1.Source_Station_Name_1 as Source_Station,
(Select Top 1 Last_Value(t4.Station_Name) over (Partition by T4.Train_No Order BY t4.islno ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) from Rail t4 where t4.Train_No=T1.Train_No) as Connecting_Station1,
(Select Top 1 Last_Value(t4.Station_Name) over (Partition by T4.Train_No Order BY t4.islno ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) from Rail t4 where t4.Train_No=T2.Train_No) as Connecting_Station2,
(Select Top 1 LAST_Value(t4.Station_Name) over (Partition by T4.Train_No Order BY t4.islno ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) from Rail t4 where t4.Train_No=T3.Train_No) as Connecting_Station3,
t4.Destination_Station_Name_1 as Destination_Station,
(Select Top 1 Convert(time,Last_Value(t5.Depature_time) over (Partition by T5.Train_No Order BY t5.islno ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)) from Rail t5 where t5.Train_No=T1.Train_No) as DP_T1L,
(Select Top 1 Convert(time,First_Value(t5.Depature_time) over (Partition by T5.Train_No Order BY t5.islno ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)) from Rail t5 where t5.Train_No=T2.Train_No) as DP_T2F,
(Select Top 1 Convert(time,Last_Value(t5.Depature_time) over (Partition by T5.Train_No Order BY t5.islno ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)) from Rail t5 where t5.Train_No=T2.Train_No) as DP_T2L,
(Select Top 1 Convert(time,First_Value(t5.Depature_time) over (Partition by T5.Train_No Order BY t5.islno ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)) from Rail t5 where t5.Train_No=T3.Train_No) as DP_T3F,
(Select Top 1 Convert(time,Last_Value(t5.Depature_time) over (Partition by T5.Train_No Order BY t5.islno ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)) from Rail t5 where t5.Train_No=T3.Train_No) as DP_T3L,
(Select Top 1 Convert(time,First_Value(t5.Depature_time) over (Partition by T5.Train_No Order BY t5.islno ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)) from Rail t5 where t5.Train_No=T4.Train_No) as DP_T4F,
CASE
    WHEN t1.Train_Name LIKE '%Exp' and t1.Train_Name NOT LIKE  '%SF Exp%' THEN 50
    WHEN t1.Train_Name Like '%Pass%' THEN 33
    WHEN t1.Train_Name LIKE '%SF Exp%' THEN 60
    ELSE 50 END as AvgSpeed_1,
CASE
    WHEN t2.Train_Name LIKE '%Exp' and t2.Train_Name NOT LIKE  '%SF Exp%' THEN 50
    WHEN t2.Train_Name Like '%Pass%' THEN 33
    WHEN t2.Train_Name LIKE '%SF Exp%' THEN 60
    ELSE 50 END as AvgSpeed_2,
CASE
    WHEN t3.Train_Name LIKE '%Exp' and t3.Train_Name NOT LIKE  '%SF Exp%' THEN 50
    WHEN t3.Train_Name Like '%Pass%' THEN 33
    WHEN t3.Train_Name LIKE '%SF Exp%' THEN 60
    ELSE 50 END as AvgSpeed_3,
CASE
    WHEN t4.Train_Name LIKE '%Exp' and t4.Train_Name NOT LIKE  '%SF Exp%' THEN 50
    WHEN t4.Train_Name Like '%Pass%' THEN 33
    WHEN t4.Train_Name LIKE '%SF Exp%' THEN 60
    ELSE 50 END as AvgSpeed_4
from Rail t1
join Rail t2 on (t2.Source_Station_Name=t1.Destination_Station_Name)
join Rail t3 on (t3.Source_Station_Name=t2.Destination_Station_Name)
JOIN RAIL t4 on (t4.Source_Station_Name=t3.Destination_Station_Name)
where t1.Source_Station_Name_1 Like @StartLocation
and t4.Destination_Station_Name_1 Like @EndLocation
),
T2 AS (
SELECT Train_1,Train_Name1,Train_2,Train_Name2,Train_3,Train_Name3,Train_4,Train_Name4 ,Source_Station,Connecting_Station1,Connecting_Station2,Connecting_Station3,Destination_Station,(Distance_1+Distance_2+Distance_3+Distance_4) as TotalDistance,
CASE
    WHEN DP_T2F < DP_T1L
    THEN DATEDIFF(HH,DP_T1L,DP_T2F)+24
    ELSE DATEDIFF(HH,DP_T1L,DP_T2F) 
    END as Waiting_Time_1,
CASE
    WHEN DP_T3F < DP_T2L
    THEN DATEDIFF(HH,DP_T2L,DP_T3F)+24
    ELSE DATEDIFF(HH,DP_T2L,DP_T3F) 
    END as Waiting_Time_2,
CASE
    WHEN DP_T4F < DP_T3L
    THEN DATEDIFF(HH,DP_T3L,DP_T4F)+24
    ELSE DATEDIFF(HH,DP_T3L,DP_T4F) 
    END as Waiting_Time_3,
CAST(Distance_1/AvgSpeed_1 as decimal(18,2)) as Travelling_Time_1,
CAST(Distance_2/AvgSpeed_2 as decimal(18,2)) as Travelling_Time_2,
CAST(Distance_3/AvgSpeed_3 as decimal(18,2)) as Travelling_Time_3,
CAST(Distance_4/AvgSpeed_4 as decimal(18,2)) as Travelling_Time_4       
FROM T1
)
SELECT TOP 1 (Train_1+'-'+Train_2+'-'+Train_3+'-'+Train_4)as Train_No,(LTRIM(RTRIM(Source_Station))+'-'+LTRIM(RTRIM(Connecting_Station1))+'-'+LTRIM(RTRIM(Connecting_Station2))+'-'+LTRIM(RTRIM(Connecting_Station3))+'-'+LTRIM(RTRIM(Destination_Station)))as Train_Route,TotalDistance,(Waiting_Time_1+Waiting_Time_2+Waiting_Time_3) as Waiting_Time,(Travelling_Time_1+Travelling_Time_2+Travelling_Time_3+Travelling_Time_4) as Travelling_Time,Source_Station,Destination_Station FROM T2
ORDER BY TotalDistance,Travelling_Time
END
```

I am also getting the output as desired but it is taking more time to execute so how can I optimize it.

Comment: start by looking at the output of explain

Comment: MYSQL and sqlserver both tagged?

Comment: IT is written in SQL Server

Comment: Please provide execution plan

Comment: What if some _strange_ train has more then 4 stations on the route?

Comment: @VivekMoningi, include DDL (with constraints indexes), for the referenced tables.  Are the station names really varchar(MAX)?  Consider varchar(n) instead unless you need more than 8,000 characters.  Also, LIKE with leading wildcards will perform better with a SQL collation rather than a Windows collation.